# C# Text Writer writes at the start of the file

Tags: c#

My class which holds the constructor method of writing to a file

```
class Writer
    {
        public Writer(string filename, List<string> data)
        {
            FileStream ostrm;
            StreamWriter writer;
            TextWriter oldOut = Console.Out;
            try
            {
                ostrm = new FileStream("C:/Users/kyle/Desktop/ConferenceSoftware/" + filename + ".txt", FileMode.OpenOrCreate, FileAccess.Write);
                writer = new StreamWriter( ostrm );
            }
            catch (Exception e)
            {
                Console.WriteLine("Cannot open " + filename + ".txt for writing");
                Console.WriteLine(e.Message);
                return;
            }


 Console.SetOut(writer);
            foreach (var _data in data)
            {
                Console.WriteLine( _data );
            }
            Console.SetOut(oldOut);
            writer.Close();
            ostrm.Close();
        }
    }
```

Inside my main method:

```
List<string> dataToAdd = new List<string>();
dataToAdd.Add("Example");
new Writer(Settings.ConferenceRoomName, dataToAdd);
```

However, if I already have text inside the file, instead appending to the file from the last line, it does it from the first line, ie:

```
Example // new added through method
Line that already exists // already in file
Line that already exists // already in file
// this is where I wanted it but it goes to the top
```

Any help would be appreciated, I don't see where I could target what line to start writing at.

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You need to use `FileMode.Append` instead of `OpenOrCreate`:

```
ostrm = new FileStream("C:/Users/kyle/Desktop/ConferenceSoftware/" + 
                   filename + ".txt", FileMode.Append, FileAccess.Write);
```

See [documentation](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.io.filemode) (about `FileMode.Append`):

> Opens the file if it exists and seeks to the end of the file, or creates a new file. This requires FileIOPermissionAccess.Append permission. FileMode.Append can be used only in conjunction with FileAccess.Write...

So it will also create the file if it does not exist.
If you don't want to create a non-existing file, you can check if it exists using [`File.Exists()`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.io.file.exists) before opening the stream.

Comment: Hit the nail on the head, works like a charm and I don't need to worry about creating files. Thanks for this - I will mark it as soon as I can! :)

Answer (score 3):

When you create a new `FileStream` with `FileMode.OpenOrCreate`, it writes over the existing file. If you would like to append to the file, use `FileMode.Append` instead:

> `FileMode.Append`: Opens the file if it exists and seeks to the end of the file, or creates a new file. This requires `FileIOPermissionAccess.Append` permission.

```
ostrm = new FileStream("C:/Users/kyle/Desktop/ConferenceSoftware/" + filename + ".txt", FileMode.Append, FileAccess.Write);
```

Comment: I could possibly stick a switch statement on check file exists or a try catch depending on whether I create a new one or append it? because in some cases I do want to create a file, thanks for this!

Comment: @KyleE4K You could check `ostrm.Position` after opening. If it is zero, you have just created a new file, or the old one was empty; otherwise, you are appending.

Comment: @KyleE4K you can use `File.Exists(...)` to check if it exists before creating it.

Comment: @RenéVogt This may lead to hard to find errors if there are other processes trying to write the same file concurrently. `File.Exists` may return `false`, but the file may exist when you create `FileStream` in the next millisecond, because another process has just written to it.

Comment: @dasblinkenlight That is correct, but there is no (easy) way to avoid _those_ kind of problems.No matter how you check it. Between the check and the opening/creation someone else could always have created/deleted/locked the file.

Comment: @RenéVogt Checking file stream position after creation with append mode is free from this problem, because the decision to create or to append is done atomically from your program's perspective.

Answer (score 1):

You want file mode `Append` instead of `OpenOrCreate`:

```
ostrm = new FileStream("C:/Users/kyle/Desktop/ConferenceSoftware/" + filename + ".txt", FileMode.Append, FileAccess.Write);
```

Both will create a new file if it doesn't exist, the difference is that `OpenOrCreate` starts writing at the beginning of the file and `Append` starts writing at the end of the file.

Reference: [FileMode Enumeration](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.io.filemode%28v=vs.110%29.aspx)